# Angular Exchange information between controller and other scripts

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

My problem is little bit unusual. In my angular app I need to use double range slider build as a jQuery plugin. So I included additional script file where I initiated that plugin and all of it's options. However some of those options are not fixed and have to be changed up to the user's decisions. More precisely value chosen by the user in dropdown menu (< select>< option>) should be a range of that slider.

And here is where my problem appears. Since this select-option field is located inside < div ng-if=""> < /div> tag my other script files cannot recognize it and I can't simply use jQuery methods to fetch those values nor detect any changes.

Only solution which I see for now is to create a new input (invisible for the user) connected with my slider through ng-model and fetch this value to my another script file by it. However this notion makes code very messy and illegible. So I wonder if there is a way to directly connect my controller with script like this:

ng-model from select field -> angular controller -> script

Answer (score 0):

change < div ng-if="">  to  < div ng-show="">

sometimes ng-if is not working properly